# PHP specific images not aligning

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make all images be displayed side by side with the following code:

```
<div id = "all-container">
  <?php 

  $dir = "images/";
  $arr = scandir($dir);

  foreach ($arr as $img) {
    if ($img != '.' && $img != '..') {
      echo "<div class = 'img-container'><img class = 'image' src = 'images/$img'></div>";
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

This is class 'img-container' in CSS:

```
.img-container {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Apparently, this seems to work when I set the image source to some [random picture](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8UaKu8jOnzlj5MaIYRgpDAWWuGKRvtR5fNI9PX1STMSi0KZvmcyOy0A0) from the internet.

But when I use my own images, they're still displayed top to bottom.
The images I'm using are the Windows 7 Sample Pictures (1024 x 768 in size, JPG).

I tried many times, and if I just change the source of the image, it seems to work.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You don't need `inline-block` when you're using float. The float images will show next to each other if the width of them is not bigger than your document's (or parent div's) width. So if you're using 1024x768 images, they will show next to each other if your screen is bigger than 2048.

Comment: check width of your images if width is more than screen width to adjust then other image will be in new line automatically

Comment: just bootstrap it and don't use such large images; use thumbnailing

Comment: even if i set the size to 10%, they're top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should nest img tags like below:

```
<div class = 'img-container'>
<img class = 'image' src ='http://lorempixel.com/200/200'>
<img class = 'image' src ='http://lorempixel.com/200/200'>
</div>
```

But your code will create div tag with img-container class each time it repeats;
you will need to print out :

```
<div class = 'img-container'>
```

before foreach and

```
</div> /*end of img-container div tag*/
```

after it.

Comment: Thanks! They're side-by-side now.